# SSL wrap socket: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'

Tags: python, ssl

I'm creating a very simple example on OSX with python 2.6 but I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket, ssl
  File "/Users/Dennis/ssl.py", line 5, in <module>
    sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

Code:

```
import socket, ssl

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('irc.freenode.net', 7000))
sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
print repr(sslSocket.server())
print repr(sslSocket.issuer())
sslSocket.write('Hello secure socket\n')
s.close()
```

What am I doing terribly wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't name your script `ssl.py`, because  when you name your script `ssl.py` and you do `import ssl` you're importing this same script .

Comment: Thanks! That helped! Now I only need to fix     print repr(sslSocket.server())
AttributeError: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: @FLX: glad it help :) about your new problem have you checked the documentation http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html#sslsocket-objects there is no method `server()` in the class `SSLSocket` ??

Comment: Right! I came to that conclusion after 10 seconds of thinking. All is working now, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your script is : `ssl.py`

When you do an `import ssl`, it calls itself and that is why you get the `AttributeError`

Give another name to your script and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't name your own script `ssl.py` and use Python 3.12 or newer, this is expected:

> Remove the `ssl.wrap_socket()` function, deprecated in Python 3.7: instead, create a `ssl.SSLContext` object and call its `ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket` method. Any package that still uses `ssl.wrap_socket()` is broken and insecure.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#ssl